# Base64Binary interpreted as byte[][]

Tags: java, c#, wsdl

I have an issue with generating a client proxy in VS 2015 where the reference generated from the WSDL interprets a base64Binary object as a byte[][].

Here's the WSDL section:

```
  <xs:complexType name="putPlanning">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="data" type="xs:base64Binary" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And in the generated reference:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="xxx.xxx.xxx", Order=8)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("data", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="base64Binary")]
    public byte[][] data;
```

I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the generation of the WSDL at the Java web service, but could anyone with a little more experience shine a light on what might be the cause on either the client or server side?

I would expect that base64Binary translates as string[] and not byte[][].

This is failing to work as i expect the webservice wants base64 strings but the client proxy is forcing a byte[][] array of arrays.

Further Info:

In SOAPUI the following code work with this web-service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:psw="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <psw:putPlanning>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <data>*base64string==*</data>
         <data>*base64string==*</data>
      </psw:putPlanning>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

so this tells me an array of base64 strings (actual base64 string ommited as they are too long) is accepted. So the question is, why did Visual Studio generate a byte[][] datatype based on the WSDL?

Comment: `...could anyone with a little more experience shine a light on what might be the cause...?` The cause of _what?_

Comment: "Base64Binary interpreted as byte[][]" ... i don't think it should be :)

Comment: But xs:base64Binary should be interpreted at the client as a string[] and not byte[][]...am i missing something as that's the whole problem here, a byte[][] is not correct as the web service expects an array of base64 strings, not a byte array of byte arrays.

Comment: The data itself is stored as byte arrays, but when it gets serialized, for example with an `XmlSerializer`, it gets converted into a Base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

By default JAXB uses `byte[]` mapping for `Base64Binary` xsd datatype.

All of these bindings can be overridden on global or case-by-case levels by means of a custom binding declaration.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazq.html